# Control (0 - 10 V) fan from LM358

Tags: esp32, comparator, dac, gain, offset

I want to generate output of (0 - 10 V) from ESP32 GPIO (0 - 3.3 V). Basically fan is connected to the output. I am attaching a circuit of it. Do I need any changes in the design or it will work? Will the gain be uniform throughout 0 to 10 V?

[image]

Comment: Are you using an ultra-miniature fan that draws ≤20 mA?

Comment: yes, I am using ultra miniature fan for cooling purpose

Comment: The last part, its current draw, is the important part. What are the electrical specs of your fan?

Comment: Are you really using a 5 V supply on the LM358 and expecting to get 10 V out?

Comment: An opamp is not magic - it can't produce an output that's higher than its supply voltage.

Comment: So i should add a boost converter that will convert 5v to10v and then give that 10v to Opamp? or Input supply should be higher than 10V if output is 10V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an op-amp alone will probably not be strong enough to run your fan,
add a transistor to boost the output current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs4NLr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>